# how do I find the distance between a vector and a span of a set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of vectors $A = \{ v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ and an additional vector $w$ all in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I want an algorithm that finds the distance between $w$ and the span of $A$.

What would be an algorithm for doing that?

EDIT: Would it be correct, following DonAntonio's question, that if I calculate an orthonormal basis for $span(A)$ using Gram-Schmidt, leading to $A' = \{ b_1, \ldots, b_n \}$ and then compute $$d = ||w - \sum_{i=1}^n <b_i, w> b_i||_2$$ then I will get the distance?

Comment: What distance do you have in $\;\Bbb R^d\;$ ? Is there some inner product, I believe...

Comment: @DonAntonio Regular Euclidean distance, $||x-y||_2$.

Comment: Well then, can you evaluate the orthogonal projection of $\;w\;$ onto $\;Span\,A\;$ ?

Comment: This is a least squares problem: you want to minimize $\|Ax - w\|_2$.  An optimal $x$ could be obtained by solving the "normal equations" $A^T A x = A^T w$.  Other algorithms for solving least squares problems are given in numerical linear algebra.  In Matlab the command x = A\w; gives an optimal x.

Comment: Oh, I was using $A$ to denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.

Comment: About your question, @linalg: yes.

Answer (score 2):

Summary of approaches offered in comments:

1. $x=Pw$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the span of $A$. One can find $P$ by orthonormalizing $A$; then $Pw=\sum \langle w,u_i\rangle u_i$.
2. Solve the "normal equations" $A^T Ax=A^Tw$
3. Use `x=A\w` in Matlab (or Scilab).

Comment: why do we require the span to be orthonormal? will the projection of the vector onto the basis without orthonormalizing them not work?